# Translate Stata to R: keeping values using information of two different columns

Tags: r, filtering, stata

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(date= c("2011-11-01", "2011-11-01", "2011-11-01", "2011-11-01"), 
                 reference_year=c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), 
                 mean=c(6.49, 5.55, 5.05, 4.87))
```

So I would like to create a new data frame with the mean in the cases where the year of the date (2011) be equal to year of the date + 1 (2012).

Using Stata I did just using this code:

```
gen eventtime=date(date, "YMD")
gen day=day(eventtime)
gen month=month(eventtime)
gen yr=year(eventtime)    
keep if reference_year == yr+1    
collapse (first) mean date, by(eventtime)
```

However, as a R beginner, I would like to do in R.

Comment: So where exactly are you getting stuck? What have you tried? Right now this reads like you just want someone to translate this code from one language to another and that's not the type of question/request that's on-topic for Stack Overflow. Also, give the desired output so those unfamiliar with Stata can still try to answer. This way possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: Apparently ['keep' in Stata means the equivalent of 'filter' in R](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/selecting-subset-of-observations/). Please read through R and dplyr tutorials to learn the R terminology.

Answer (score 1):

As an R beginner, the following may not make a whole lot of sense. But essentially, I'm splitting the `date` variable into 3 variables (`year`, `month`, `day`) and then I filter to the `reference_year - 1`. The `%>%` is called a "pipe" and can be read as "and then do this".

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(date= c("2011-11-01", "2011-11-01", "2011-11-01", "2011-11-01"), 
                 reference_year=c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), 
                 mean=c(6.49, 5.55, 5.05, 4.87))

new_df <- df %>% 
  separate(date, c("year", "month", "day"), sep = "-") %>% 
  filter(year == (reference_year - 1))
#>   year month day reference_year mean
#> 1 2011    11  01           2012 5.55
```

Comment: Really Thank you @Phil! That's exactly what I want. However, I would like to create a new data frame with this new data. Is it possible? I tried df1<-filter(year == (reference_year - 1)) but it doesn't works. Best Regards.

Comment: Exactly that! I found this answer searching the site. Really really thank you @Phil!